# How to auto delete Facebook account if I pass away?

Tags: facebook

Has Facebook this feature in its API?

I did a *[Request account deletion](https://www.facebook.com/help/103897939701143)* but someone should tell Facebook that the fact was fulfilled through this [form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/228813257197480).

How can I auto fill out this form and submit it or send a delete account request to the Facebook API after my activity has not been confirmed in an external service?

Comment: There is no automated way.

Comment: Yeah, that'd be a fun one to hack into, if it existed ... could lend so much more credibility to fake news politician/celebrity death stories ... maybe you should submit it as a feature request.